# Importing external into my own SVN repository

Tags: svn, version-control, repository, tortoisesvn, svn-externals

I use TortoiseSVN to keep track of a few projects. One of my repositories (let's call it "Repo A") has an external which is a certain folder from another "Repo B", but from now on I need to commit certain changes to this folder and these changes are related only to Repo A.

I could, of course, add a manual copy of the folder to my repository and start committing, but this comes with two disadvantages:

- It's a rather large folder, and this will consume more disk space as SVN doesn't know the folder is simply a copy from another Repo (at a certain rev. number)
- The previous commit logs to this folder (from Repo B) won't show up when viewing the history for Repo A.

What I want to do basically is to "fork" the folder into another Repository.
Is there an intuitive way of doing this?

Comment: I can't link "keep those changes limited to my repository" and "disadvantage: consuming much more disk space in my SVN server". If you want to have it in own repo, you have to be ready for it and **store in repo**

Comment: Still it's a valid question. I edited to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

- You can't physically move folder from repo to repo and don't have
  some additional space "wasted" - repositories are independent
  entities and all it's objects must be kept in it
- But you can have
  this folder in RepoA with all history from RepoB: just perform
  dump|load cycle for folder in question( `svnadmin dump`+
  `svndumpfilter` or `svnrdump dump` for getting dump of repo's part)